# Optimise jQuery .addClass on :nth-child(x)

Tags: jquery, addclass

I am looking for a way to optimise the following:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(12n-5)').addClass('bk');
$('ul li:nth-child(12n-4)').addClass('bk95');
$('ul li:nth-child(12n-3)').addClass('bk90');
$('ul li:nth-child(12n-2)').addClass('bk85');
$('ul li:nth-child(12n-1)').addClass('bk80');
$('ul li:nth-child(12n+1)').addClass('bk75');
$('ul li:nth-child(12n+2)').addClass('bk70');
$('ul li:nth-child(12n+3)').addClass('bk75');
$('ul li:nth-child(12n+4)').addClass('bk80');
$('ul li:nth-child(12n+5)').addClass('bk85');
$('ul li:nth-child(12n+6)').addClass('bk90');
$('ul li:nth-child(12n-7)').addClass('bk95');
```

Any suggestions welcome

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any way to map the class name with the index of the child?  Should the last line of code be `12n+7`?

Comment: Isn't `12n` missing and `12n+7` (after correcting the typo) is just the same as `12n-5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var classes = ['bk75' /*for 12n*/, 'bk70' /*for 12n+1*/, ..., 'bk80' /*for 12n+11 = 12n-1*/];
$('ul').children('li').each(function (i) {
  $(this).addClass(classes[i % 12]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it looks to have solved the issues I was having and the script seems a lot more responsive.